# Python version mismatch error while configuring the RBTools on mac osx

Tags: python, macos, review-board

I was trying to configure the RBTools on mac os but i am facing an issue with setting up the repo. 
This is the error am getting.

```
ImportError: Python minor version mismatch: The Mercurial extension modules were compiled with Python 2.7.5, but Mercurial is currently using Python with sys.hexversion=33949936: Python 2.6.8 (unknown, Mar  9 2014, 22:16:00) \n', '[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)]\n', ' at: /usr/bin/python\n'
```

I have installed RBTools v0.7.4 with python version 2.6.8 and i have python version 2.7.5 as well.

This is the complete traceback   http://pastie.org/10332044

Am getting this error when i try to run the rbt setup-repo.

Any help on this would be of great help am struck with this from past one week.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug in the RBTools assembly. I filed [this ticket](https://hellosplat.com/s/beanbag/tickets/4020/) for it. See more details on how I troubleshot there, but specifically, go look at `/usr/local/bin/rbt` and change the shebang from `python2.6` to `python` and you should be good.